# ASP.NET Web widget deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created my first simple widget. It has some textboxes for input and output data and a button. After clicking it, it connects to web service through soap and send back needed data. Now, I've stumbled upon the issue of its deployment. What's the simplest way to deploy it on any sample site without it interfering with the content? How do I approach this and what should I do?

Here's my WebForm.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WidgetTest3.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to deploy this from within Visual Studio is to use the Build -> Publish  command and choose the File System publish method.

To prevent it from interfering with existing files, make sure that the "Delete all existing files prior to publish" is unchecked in the File Publish Options section of the Publish Web dialog.

Comment: You were right. I was by far the best way. Thank you.